# Can XML Documentation be used with runtime-packages

Tags: delphi, xml-documentation, runtime-packages

I'm working on a new project with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, where I would like to use Runtime Packages to give other developers the possibility to use parts of my code in their own projects. So I created a Runtime Package and used it in another Delphi VCL project via the "Runtime-Packages" option to test if everything works as expected. Technically, it works, but in my code I have some XML Documentation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/XML_Documentation_Comments

Inside the Package, everything works as expected. If the source is compiled and used in another application, the XML Documentation is gone. I also enabled creating XML Documentation in the Compiler options, and set the Output folder to the same folder as the BPLs. Here is some demo code that works correctly:

```pascal
unit unit1;

interface

type
/// <summary> Represents a Democlass
/// </summary>
  TDemo = class
    // ...
end;

implementation

var
  Demo : TDemo;
```

I have searched the web for some time, but cannot find anything near my problem.  I hope there is a solutions for that, or at least a good answer why it could not work.

Comment: XML documentation is only really useful when editing/compiling source code. If you use a pre-compiled Package binary in a project, the XML documentation in its source code will not be accessible to the IDE. Even if you distribute the generated `.xml` file, the IDE still won't use it, IIRC. You would need to use something like [DevJet Documentation Insight](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/documentation-insight/) to view external `.xml` files in the IDE, or to convert them to a format that can then be installed into the IDE's help system.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Have found that link also by searching the web. The Solution ist not satisfactory but OK :) Thanks also for correcting my horrible english grammer and typos :-D